# Ionic Slider loop true

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js

As I know Ionic slider using Swiper JS 

I put the loop on true but it not looping

it reach the final slide and stop

here is my config

```
Config= {
    initialSlide: 0,
    slidesPerView: 1,
    speed: 400,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 1000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-slides
  #slides
  [options]="Config"
  loop="true"
>
  <ion-slide>{{"slide-1"}}</ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>{{"slide-2"}}</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Put "loop" as true in your html (as above). This worked for me..